# How to Fetch 1.7 Million records in Java?

Tags: java, mysql, linux, centos5

I am using MySQL database in which a table has 1.7 million records. Through Restlet framework in Java I want to fetch these records and return it to the client. I am using Linux Centos which is remote server. I have created WAR file and uploaded on the server. When I run the service it is taking lot of time to respond. I waited for 40 mins but not getting any output.
   So Can anybody please help me to resolve this problem?

Comment: I would advice you that you add some sort of pagination and allow client to specify offset of records and limit records to n in every fetch. That can simplify your problem. 1.7 million records over REST in single go definitely sounds too much

Comment: Why on Earth would you ever want to even attempt to pull that many records?

Comment: are you planning to show entire 1.7million records to client? i am afraid your browser will also be not be able to handle that.

Comment: If Google return that many records when you search for something and then let the browser do the paging, Google will not exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I have a very large number of rows I have used memory mapped files. e.g. I have one database where I have to retrieve and process 1.1 billion rows in around a minute. (Its over 200 GB)

This is a very specialist approach, and I suspect there is a way to tune your SQL database or use a NoSQL database to do what you want. I would have though you can retrieve 1.7 million in under a minute depending on what you are doing (e.g. if you are selecting this many amoungst a few TB its going to take a while)

But, if there really is no other option, you could write a custom data store.

BTW: Only a summary is produced.  No one should be expected to read that many rows, certainly not display them in a browser.  Perhaps there is something you can do to produce a report or summary so there is less to send the client.

Comment: Hi Peter, Thanks for reply. yes I am selecting the records from one table with the result of other tables.

Comment: In that case, the first think to check would be your indexes are optimial for the join between tables.

Answer (score 4):

That's probably not going to work: holding that many rows of data in memory will probably cause an out of memory exception (can you look at the logs on the server and see what exactly is happening?).

To do something like this you'll either need to abandon that plan and do pagination of some sort, or you'll need a solution that lets you stream the records to the client without holding them in memory. I'm unsure that the Restlet framework lets you do that: you'll probably need to implement that using servlets yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully done just this kind of work in my apps. If your client is ready to accept a big response, there is nothing wrong with the approach. The main point is that you'll need to stream the response, which means you can't build te entire response as a string. Get the outputstream of the HTTP response and write records into it one by one. On the db-end you need to set up a scrollable resultset (easy to do at the JDBC level, as well as at the Hibernate level).

Comment: Hi Marko, thanks for reply. I am using the scrollable resultset, I'll try this with the outputstream of the HTTP.